# Trouble using GROUP BY in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have created a table with the below command.

```
CREATE TABLE student
(sid int,sname varchar(20), email varchar(25), phone varchar(10),tfee float,feepaid float,course varchar(2),branch varchar(3),city varchar(15));
```

Now when I try to create a static view(for static view we need to use a group by clause). but its giving me an error.  Here is my query.

```
CREATE VIEW sacview as 
SELECT sid,sname,tfee,feepaid,course,branch 
FROM student 
GROUP BY sid;
```

The error is not a group by expression. I have no idea why? everything seems all right to me.

Comment: To downvoter, leave your comment as to why you are voting this question down..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, `sid` is *already`unique in the`student` table.  So, this is probably what you want:

```
CREATE VIEW sacview as 
    SELECT sid, sname, tfee, feepaid, course, branch 
    FROM student ;
```

If you are concerned about duplicates (and that probably suggests another problem), you can use `distinct`:

```
CREATE VIEW sacview as 
    SELECT DISTINT sid, sname, tfee, feepaid, course, branch 
    FROM student ;
```

The problem with `group by sid` is the remaining columns in the `select`.  Assuming `sid` really is unique, then more recent versions of the ANSI standard support your syntax, but Oracle (and most other databases) do not implement this functionality.  You could do what you are attempting as:

```
CREATE VIEW sacview as 
    SELECT sid, sname, tfee, feepaid, course, branch 
    FROM student
    GROUP BY sid, sname, tfee, feepaid, course, branch ;
```

But the `distinct` does the same thing.

EDIT:

You can select an arbitrary row per `sid` using `row_number()`:

```
CREATE VIEW sacview as 
    SELECT sid, sname, tfee, feepaid, course, branch 
    FROM (SELECT s.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sid ORDER BY sid) as seqnum
          FROM student
         ) t
    WHERE seqnum = 1 ;
```

Comment: No Sid is not unique, An user by name erırverdigeldik, had given me an hint that we need to use aggregate function in Oracle query and he was right. But what aggregate function should I use as sum, avg, min are useless.

Comment: @user2900314 . . . You have to decide which values to keep among the different rows.  We can't make that decision for you.  I do hope the table does have a unique id; it is a good idea in all tables.

Comment: Was able to figure it out finally, the Syntax is 

create view <view_name> as select sid,sname,tfee,feepaid,course,branch from student with read only constraint <constraint_Name>;

Thank you @Gordon Linoff. for your time.